# Openai API issue migration

Tags: openai-api

The target of my script was to create a chatbot to review PDFs in a specific folder in my google drive.

I get the following error when trying to get the embeddings " AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'completion'"

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3064c18088c8> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Get embeddings for text chunks using GPT-3
----> 2 chunk_embeddings = get_embeddings(text_chunks)

<ipython-input-41-5fd2b5ee0712> in get_embeddings(text_chunks)
      4     embeddings = []
      5     for chunk in text_chunks:
----> 6         response = openai.completion.create(
      7             model="text-davinci-003",
      8             prompt=chunk,

AttributeError: module 'openai' has no attribute 'completion'
```

The initial issue is an AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'completion,' suggesting that the OpenAI module does not have a 'completion' attribute.

The attempted fix involves running 'openai migrate,' which encounters multiple problems, including parsing errors in various files, some related to UTF-8 encoding, and others involving source code parsing.

[Snip error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV5F7.png)

```
from google.colab import drive
# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/MyDrive')

# Install  packages

# Import libraries

# Get the API key from the 'secretName' in userdata
openai_api_key = userdata.get('OPENAI_API_KEY')

# Create an instance of the OpenAI client with the API key
client = openai.OpenAI(api_key=openai_api_key)

# function to mount Google Drive
def mount_drive():
    drive.mount("/content/MyDrive", force_remount=True)

def get_vectorstore(text_chunks, api_key):
    # Use OpenAI's create method to get completions for text chunks
    chunk_completions = [openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-003",
        prompt=chunk,
        max_tokens=1024,
        n=1,
        temperature=0.7,
        stop=None
    )["choices"][0]["text"] for chunk in text_chunks]

    # Create a vector store using FAISS
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(texts=chunk_completions, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(api_key=api_key))

    return vectorstore

# function to get embeddings for text chunks using GPT
def get_embeddings(text_chunks):
    embeddings = []
    for chunk in text_chunks:
        response = openai.completion.create(
            model="text-davinci-003",
            prompt=chunk,
            max_tokens=1024,
            n=1,
            temperature=0.7,
            stop=None
        )
        embedding = response['choices'][0]['text']
        embeddings.append(embedding)
    return embeddings

# function to create a vector store using FAISS
def create_vector_store(embeddings):
    # Convert embeddings to vectors
    vectors = [np.frombuffer(embedding.encode('utf-8'), dtype=np.float32) for embedding in embeddings]
    matrix = np.vstack(vectors)

    # Create a FAISS index
    index = faiss.IndexFlatIP(matrix.shape[1])
    index.add(matrix)
    return index

# function to get text from PDF
def get_pdf_text(pdf_docs):
    text = ""
    for pdf in pdf_docs:
        pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf)
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    return text

# function to create overlapping text chunks
def get_text_chunks(text):
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(
        separator="\n",
        chunk_size=1000,
        chunk_overlap=200,
        length_function=len
    )
    chunks = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    return chunks

# Example path to PDF
path_to_pdf = ['/.../X.pdf']

# Get text from PDF
raw_text = get_pdf_text(path_to_pdf)

# Get text chunks
text_chunks = get_text_chunks(raw_text)

# Get embeddings for text chunks using GPT-3
chunk_embeddings = get_embeddings(text_chunks)
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.